# getting around octave's lack of map data structure

Tags: arrays, matlab, dictionary, octave, associative-array

i am using octave for my project as i cant afford a matlab license, however i have run into a significant roadblock and that is the lack of associative array data structures.

my problem is this:

i have some data in the form of cell arrays containing matrices with each cell array representing a potential solution to a problem. i also have a floating point number that represents the evaluated performance of that solution which i want to put into a map-like data structure with the floating point score as the key, in order to sort the solutions by their performance.

can anyone suggest a simple solution to this problem?

what i have thought about doing so far is making each element part of a two element cell array, with the evaluation score as the first element and the data as the second, and then put those arrays into another cell array, which i then apply some sorting algorithm to, sorting by array{i}{1}.. but this seems like a pretty clunky solution.

does octave have any functionality in this respect that i am just unaware of? or is my clunky solution the only way to achieve this?

any help would be greatly appreciated
thanks

Comment: In Matlab the best solution is structure array. http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/create-a-structure-array.html

Comment: that doesnt allow me to sort by key though does it?

Comment: http://blogs.mathworks.com/pick/2010/09/17/sorting-structure-arrays-based-on-fields/ See comments

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about keeping the cell array as it is, but create a matrix where the columns are the evaluation score and the index into the cell array. Then you can easily use sortrows on the evaluation score column and use the index to pull the solution from the cell array. I think this should be a simple solution that has the benefit of not rearranging your potentially large set of data.

Comment: that makes a lot of sense! definitely better than rearranging the dataset all the time too..